# Rails Get data from form (saves in database) and display it / use it again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Ok so this is a noobie question. I have made a form that saves the data to a database from a form.

I want to then display the data in a view or a controller that i got from the form.

Here is my code for the form.

Controller:
msgs_controller.rb

```
class MsgsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @msg = Msg.new
    @msgs = Msg.all
  end

  def create
    @msg = Msg.new(msg_params)
    if @msg.save
      redirect_to msgcomp_path
    end
  end

def msg_params
  params.require(:msg).permit(:name, :emails, :content, :phone)
end

end
```

view:
new.html.haml

```
 .row
  .col-md-12
    .col-md-4
      //Home page text
      .text-title
        %h1 DMS International Ltd.

      .text-norm
        %p London Heathrow: +44 (0)20 8897 1766
        Suite 207, UCH House, Old Bath Road, Colnbrook, Berkshire SL3 0NW

        %p London Gatwick: +44 (0)1293 772608
        Unit 1, Bridge Industrial Estate, Balcombe Road, Horley, Surrey RH6 9HU
    .col-md-8
      %h1 Contact DMS International

      .contactform
        = form_for @msg do |f|
          Full Name:
          %br
          = f.text_field :name 
          %br
          Email:
          %br
          = f.text_field :emails
          %br
          Phone Number:
          %br
          = f.text_field :phone
          %br
          How can we help you ?
          %br
          = f.text_field :content, :class => 'content'
          %br
          = f.submit 'submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary'

    TEMP (will be replaced with email)  Msgs:
    - @msgs.each do |msg|
      %ul
        =  msg.name
        %br
        =  msg.emails
        %br
        =  msg.content
        %br
        =  msg.phone
        %br
```

Now what i want to do is get the data from the database not just for this view but say the homepage by doing something like ? ( @msg.emails ) But i don't know how to do that.

I want to be able to get it so i can email the persons information collected from the form.

Now i really appreciate your help in the matter. I will also keep you updated if i find a solution myself but i have been looking for hours / more than one day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails the ID column is used by convention when displaying resources.
So lets say you have the following route defination:

`resources :msgs, only: [:show, :index, :new, :create]`

This would create the following routes:

```
 POST /msgs      | msgs#create
 GET /msgs/new   | msgs#new
 GET /msgs/:id   | msgs#show
 GET /msgs       | msgs#index
```

Notice the `:id` part of the show route - its whats called a dynamic segment.

Now in our controller we can create the missing actions:

```
class MsgsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @msg = Msg.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index 
    @msg = Msg.all
  end

  def new
    @msg = Msg.new
    @msgs = Msg.all
  end

  def create
    @msg = Msg.new(msg_params)
    if @msg.save
      # Redirects to our new show action
      redirect_to @msg
    end
  end

  def msg_params
    params.require(:msg).permit(:name, :emails, :content, :phone)
  end
end
```

Querying in another controller method works exactly the same. 
To find messages to a specific email address we could do something like this:

```
@msgs = Msg.where(email: 'bob@example.com')
```

## Edit:

There is no difference in querying in different controllers.

If I wanted to display all messages in my root action `Pages#home` for example:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @msgs = Msg.all
  end
end
```

---

```
-# app/views/pages/home.html.haml
- @msgs.each do |msg|
  p= msg.emails
```

Read more:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: You should probably start out by reading through the Rails guides articles at least briefly or take a beginner tutorial.

Comment: Hi there trust me i have. The issue is that i feel like im missing something. Basically as you can see currently in the view new.html.erb i can get
    = msg.emails
for example. I want to be able to get this in a different view. For example on the homepage display this information. Is it not possible to make something like that work ?

Comment: Edited the answer, there is no difference between querying in different controllers, I don't really get why you are confused about that. Maybe you should do some tutorials so that you understand the connection between parameters, querying and passing data to views.

Comment: Never mind you sexsy man you are a genius. I love you #nohomo